# How to insert a base R function into a shiny server function?

Tags: r, shiny

*(Code that resolves the question shown at the bottom, under "**Resolution**"...)*

I´m running the below R/shiny code that generates the "Output 1" shown in the image further below. The plot and 2 tables shown on the right in the image simply replicate the user inputs from the left panels. Instead, I want to run the R function called "vector", code also below, through the shiny server function that would generate the plot and 2 tables using the vector function output shown below in the image "Output 2". [Vector function works as it should. It spreads data along an even time horizon of X periods and interpolates  variables Z between time gaps defined by Y time period inputs. (X = total time horizon, Y = a specific time period to apply variable Z, and Z = the variable to apply in that time period Y). This spreads/interpolates variables across time.] So the way I see it, shiny needs to subset the matrix data() values into Y and Z columns, and the X value that the user inputs, and feed X/Y/Z into the "vector" function. And spit the vector function results back out into the shiny plot and 2 tables. I´ve tried. I don´t know how to subset the data() generated in the server function into Y and Z, and don´t know how to fit another function (like "vector") into shiny renderPlot and renderTable functions.

Here´s the R/shiny code that generates Output 1 (I inserted into the matrix, when running this app, X = 60, Y = 1,5,10, Z = 1,2,3):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

m <- matrix(c(1,1), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Y", "Z"))) 

ui <- fluidPage(   
  
  titlePanel("Input Matrix"),   
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    # Input: specify the number of observations to view in slider ----
    sliderInput("X", "Number of periods to spread data inputs along (X):",
                min = 1, max = 120, value = 60),
    
    # Input: matrix grid ----
    width = 6,     
    tags$h5(strong("Data inputs:")),     
    matrixInput("inputs",
                value = m,
                rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, editableNames = TRUE),
                cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
                class = "numeric")
    
  ), # closes sidebarPanel
  
  # Insert action button for posting data  ----
  actionButton(inputId = "go",label = "Update below:"),
  
  # Ouput to show in main panel to the right  ----  
  mainPanel(
    
    # Show input graph  ----  
    h5(strong("Plot of inputs:")),
    width = 6,plotOutput("graph"),
    
    # Show table of inputs, to be replaced with interpolated matrix ----    
    h5(strong("Table of inputs:")),
    tableOutput("view"),
    
    # TEST ----    
    h5(strong("Nbr. of periods to spread data (X):")),
    tableOutput("view1")
    
  ) # closes main panel
)   # closes user input (UI) section

server <- function(input, output, session) {   
  
  # Captures input data for further processing below in Shiny below ----
  data <- eventReactive(input$go,{input$inputs}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  spread <- eventReactive(input$go,{input$X}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # Captures input data for further processing in R (m.update is matrix name) ----
  observeEvent(data(), {m.update <<- unique(data())})
  observeEvent(spread(), {num.periods <<- unique(spread())})
  
  # Process output graph; type "l" for lines, "p" for points, "b" for combined ----  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({     
    plot(data(), type="b", main = 'Y (period) and Z (variable) plot', 
         col = "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1.25)
  }) 
  
  # Process output table, to be replaced with interpolated matrix ----    
  output$view <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
  
  # TEST ----    
  output$view1 <- renderTable({
    spread()
  })  
  
  
} # closes user server section

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here´s that vector function:

```
vector <- function(X,Y,Z){           # X for nbr periods to run, Y for period, Z for variable to apply that period                
  a <- rep(NA, X)                    # Generates elements of NA numbering X periods                           
  a[Y] <- Z                          # Places each variable Z in position indicated by its respective period Y 
  a[seq_len(min(Y)-1)] <- a[min(Y)]  # If 1st period (Y) > 1, applies that variable Z to all periods Y up to that 1st period          
  a[seq(max(Y)+1, X, 1)] <- 0        # Applies value of 0 to all periods Y after the greatest period in the period vector              
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)], 
       a[!is.na(a)], seq_along(a))$y # After the above, only NA´s remaining are periods to interpolate. This line interpolates
  return(a)
}
```

Here´s the Output 1 image:
[image]

Here´s the vector function output (interpolation etc.) using X = 60, Y = 1,5,19, Z = 1,2,3:
[image]

**Resolution:**

Now the corrected code, merging the "vector" function (crafted in base R) into a shiny object. The "vector" function is placed just above the user input (ui <-) section of shiny per YBS recommendation, and the vector function is called in the server section (key lines of code: output$view1 <- renderTable({vector(spread(),data(),1],data()[,2])})

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

m <- matrix(c(1,1), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Y", "Z"))) 

vector <- function(X,Y,Z){                    # X for number of periods to run, Y for period, Z for variable to apply that period
  a <- rep(NA, X)                             # Generates elements of NA numbering X periods
  a[Y] <- Z                                   # Places each variable Z in position indicated by its respective period Y
  a[seq_len(min(Y)-1)] <- a[min(Y)]           # If 1st period (Y) > 1, applies that variable Z to all periods Y up to that 1st period
  a[seq(max(Y)+1, X, 1)] <- 0                 # Applies value of 0 to all periods Y after the greatest period in the period vector
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)], 
              a[!is.na(a)], seq_along(a))$y   # After the above, only NA´s remaining are periods to interpolate. This line interpolates
  return(a)
}

ui <- fluidPage(   
  
  titlePanel("Input Matrix"),   
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    # Input: specify the number of observations to view in slider ----
    sliderInput("X", "Number of periods to spread data inputs along (X):",
                min = 1, max = 120, value = 60),
    
    # Input: matrix grid ----
    width = 6,     
    tags$h5(strong("Data inputs:")),     
    matrixInput("inputs",
                value = m,
                rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, editableNames = TRUE),
                cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
                class = "numeric")
    
  ), # closes sidebarPanel
  
  # Insert action button for posting data  ----
  actionButton(inputId = "go",label = "Update below:"),
  
  # Ouput to show in main panel to the right  ----  
  mainPanel(
    
    # Show input graph  ----  
    h5(strong("Plot of inputs:")),
    width = 6,plotOutput("graph"),
    
    # Show table of inputs, to be replaced with interpolated matrix ----    
    h5(strong("Table of inputs:")),
    tableOutput("view"),
    
    # TEST ----    
    h5(strong("Nbr. of periods to spread data (X):")),
    tableOutput("view1")
    
  ) # closes main panel
)   # closes user input (UI) section

server <- function(input, output, session) {   
  
  # Captures input data for further processing below in Shiny below ----
  data <- eventReactive(input$go,{input$inputs}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  spread <- eventReactive(input$go,{input$X}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # Captures input data for further processing in R (m.update is matrix name) ----
  observeEvent(data(), {m.update <<- unique(data())})
  observeEvent(spread(), {num.periods <<- unique(spread())})
  
  # Process output graph; type "l" for lines, "p" for points, "b" for combined ----  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({     
    plot(data(), type="b", main = 'Y (period) and Z (variable) plot', 
         col = "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1.25)
  }) 
  
  # Process output table, to be replaced with interpolated matrix ----    
  output$view <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
  
  # TEST ----    
  output$view1 <- renderTable({
    vector(spread(),data()[,1],data()[,2])
  })  
  
  
} # closes user server section

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can put the `vector` function above your `ui` or keep it in a separate file named `global.R`.  Then it is available for use in the server section.

Comment: Thank you YBS, that works great. Your answer was short enough where it forced me to go through and implement it in the code, helping me learn. I edit the above with the completed code in case it helps a fellow shiny neophyte.

Comment: Just a note, you can also put the `vector()` function inside the `server()` function or in the `renderTable()` function where it is used. This is useful if you only want the vector function to be available locally to certain parts of your app, so you can have other `vector()` functions elsewhere.

Comment: One other note, you may want to name the function something other than `vector` since `vector` is also a base R function. It's often used to initialize variables. Try: `?vector`